# \cmidrule not properly horizontally aligned on the outer edges & less vertical space between text lines

Tags: tables

I have included 2 new commands to add space between rows and space between columns (see code below) but doing so creates a misalignment of the `\cmidrule` (see picture below). Also, while I added space between rows it creates space between the text. Is it possible to remove this space?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array} 
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
\renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{15pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{@{} lll @{}}
 \toprule
Samples & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Observations}\\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3} 
&New & Old\\    
&Region   & Region \\
\midrule
Sample 1&1&5\\
 Sample 2&2&6\\

\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]

\end{tabular}

\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Not that it addresses the issue, but `\tabcolsep` is a length, and is set with `\tabcolsep=15pt\relax`, not `\renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{15pt}`.

Comment: Also, `&New & Old\\[-2pt] ` will remedy the vertical spacing between "New" and "Region"

Comment: Does `\cmidrule(l{2\cmidrulekern}){2-3}` provide better matching?

Comment: @Steven B. Segletes: thanks for both helpful comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The “excess” space is not unexpected, because you're setting `\tabcolsep` to 15pt, instead of the default 6pt.

The default amount of trimming is `\cmidrulekern`, at the outset 0.5em, unless you specify `l{<dimen>}` or `r{<dimen>}`. So, at 10pt size, the trimming is about the same as the default `\tabcolsep` (remember that space of the amount of `\tabcolsep` is inserted at the left and right of a column, unless countermanded by `@{<tokens>}`.

The problem on the right side is that you trim notwithstanding the trailing `@{}`, so the rule will be short of the right edge by `\cmidrulekern`.

The space between the header rows is due to `\arraystretch` being set to 1.2. You can shorten it if you set the header cells in a nested `tabular` with a standard `\arraystretch`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array} 
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{15pt}

\newcommand{\splitcell}[2][c]{%
  \begingroup
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}#1@{}}
  #2
  \end{tabular}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{@{} lll @{}}
\toprule
Samples & \multicolumn{2}{l@{}}{Observations} \\
\cmidrule(l{\tabcolsep}){2-3}
& \splitcell[l]{New \\ Region} & \splitcell[l]{Old \\ Region} \\
\midrule
Sample 1&1&5\\
Sample 2&2&6\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

Final notes: `\tabcolsep` ***must*** be set with `\setlength`, differently from `\arraystretch` (which is not a length, but a factor). The bottom rule should not be `\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]`, but simply `\bottomrule`.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I find it useful to trim 1em from the left and not trim at all from the right side of the `cmidrule`. I also included Steven Segletes suggestions. Here the first code, I also made the second and the third column centered, which I think look better; also I used `bottomrule` for the last rule

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array,multirow} 
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{15pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}lcc@{}}
 \toprule
Samples & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Observations}\\
\cmidrule(l{1em}){2-3} 
&New & Old\\[-2pt]
&Region   & Region \\
\midrule
Sample 1&1&5\\
 Sample 2&2&6\\

\bottomrule

\end{tabular}

\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Also, if you know the width of the column, you could try using multirow for "New region" and "old Region". It could be risky but you can try:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array,multirow} 
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{15pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}lcc@{}}
 \toprule
Samples & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Observations}\\
\cmidrule(l{1em}){2-3} 
&\multirow{2}{1cm}{New Region} &\multirow{2}{1cm}{Old Region}\\
&   &  \\
\midrule
Sample 1&1&5\\
 Sample 2&2&6\\

\bottomrule

\end{tabular}

\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Since you're using `booktabs`, you needn't reset `\arraystretch` manually, it does it for you. To adjust the `\cmidrule`, use `@{\hspace{30pt}}` before the second column specification and no need for `(lr)` settings. Notice that `30pt=2*15pt=2\tabcolsep`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array} 

%\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
\renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{15pt}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{\hspace{30pt}}ll@{}}
        \toprule
        Samples  & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Observations} \\ \cmidrule{2-3} 
                 & New    & Old    \\    
                 & Region & Region \\ \midrule
        Sample 1 & 1      & 5      \\
        Sample 2 & 2      & 6      \\
        \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Well, if your `30pt` is expected to be `2\tabcolsep`, why wouldn't you use `\hspace{2\tabcolsep}` directly? Anyway, `@{\hspace{2\tabcolsep}}` is a neat trick how to autotrim `\cmidrule`! Just please, **do not use `\renewcommand` on lengths**.